# Spring MongoClient getDB() is deprecated, any way to fix this without suppressing the warning?

Tags: java, mongodb, generics, spring-data-mongodb

I have a method that performs bulk write operation to a mongo database, and it working as expected.

The problem is, I am getting a deprecation warning due to `mongoClient.getDB()` as the newer version is supporting `mongoClient.getDatabase()`.

Using `DB`, I am able to get `DBCollection` which I needed to initialize unordered bulk operation, etc...  Using `mongoClient.getDatabase()`, will return MongoCollection which is not what I needed.

Is there a way that I can fix this deprecation warning without suppressing it? I mean if there is a way to use `getDatabase()` then convert `MongoCollection` into `DBCollection` yet my bulk operation will still work?

Or, it would be great if somebody can give the converted code of `bulkSaveOrUpdate()` using `MongoCollection` instead of `DBCollection`.

Below is the code of `bulkSaveOrUpdate()` method.

**Method:**

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private <T> void bulkSaveOrUpdate(List<? extends BaseModel> items) {
    String databaseName = m_mongoTemplate.getDb().getName();
    String collectionName = m_mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(items.get(0).getClass());
    DB db = m_mongoClient.getDB(databaseName);
    DBCollection collection = db.getCollection(collectionName);
    BulkWriteOperation bulkOps = collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOperation();
    MongoConverter converter = m_mongoTemplate.getConverter();
    try{
        BasicDBObject dbObject;
        for (BaseModel item : items) {
            if(item.getId() == null){
                item.setId(new ObjectId() + "");
                dbObject = new BasicDBObject();
                converter.write(item, dbObject);
                bulkOps.insert(dbObject);
            } else {
                dbObject = new BasicDBObject();
                converter.write(item, dbObject);
                BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
                query.put("_id", dbObject.get("_id"));
                BulkWriteRequestBuilder writeRequest = bulkOps.find(query);
                BulkUpdateRequestBuilder updateReq = writeRequest.upsert();
                updateReq.replaceOne(dbObject);
            }

        }
        bulkOps.execute();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        _LOG.error("Bulk upsert failed :: ", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use T extends Customer instead of T

Answer (score 0):

In order to inform the compiler that you intend to populate the collection with objects which inherits specific fields and methods from a superclass, i.e your Customer class, you can use:

```
Collection<T extends Customer> items
```

This tells the compiler that whatever object you put in the collection, it will always have the fields and methods contained in the Customer class.

Hope this provided some more clarity!

Comment: You can only set the bound of a type variable at its declaration site, e.g., `private <T extends BaseModel> void bulkSaveOrUpdate(Collection<T> items) { ...`